# I am using ng2 tostr with rxjs compact and having the following error , what can i do with that?

Tags: angular

ERROR in node_modules/ng2-toastr/src/toast-container.component.d.ts:1:48 - error TS2305: Module '"../../@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'AnimationTransitionEvent'.

1 import { ChangeDetectorRef, NgZone, OnDestroy, AnimationTransitionEvent } from '@angular/core';
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/user/signup/signup.component.ts:24:21 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ToastrManager'.

24     private toastr: ToastrManager,
~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/app.module.ts:13:28 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-toasta' or its corresponding type declarations.

13 import {ToastaModule} from 'ngx-toasta';
~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: You should add `BrowserAnimationsModule` too and what is `ngx-toasta` ? is it a typo?

Comment: its a pretty UI for alert msgs